# Hide title bar of default preference window (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Is it possible to hide the title bar of the preference window? Using `.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())` on `Settings` does not seem to have an effect unlike using it on a regular `WindowGroup`:

```
// Works
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
}
.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())

// Does not work
Settings {
   PreferencesView()
}
.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
```